# iOS Simulator button not centered

Tags: ios, xcode5

I'm following a tutorial to make a very simple game, yet I've run into a problem I can't figure out. When I center my button on the editor screen it all looks fine, but then running the app in the simulator seems to screw it all up:

[image: problem]

I'm running the latest version of XCode.

Comment: You are running this in the iPhone 4 for simulator, if its fine with the 4 inch screen then you need autolayout

Comment: Good question with a picture. Very helpful for new learners.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use autolayout to set some constraints on the button. If you don't use autolayout, the layout just uses the raw X and Y values. So in landscape, the heights of the screen are the same, but the widths are different. Your button lays out at the same X value on both screens, so one will be centered and one won't be.

Check out [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1) for more info on layout constraints.

Answer (score 3):

I was having a lot of trouble with this, too. In Xcode 6 (and Xcode 7) here is what you do.

Use a Storyboard, not XIB files. This should be the default in Xcode 6 (and Xcode 7).

Use Auto Layout and Size Classes. This should also be the default. If you click Main.storyboard in the Project Navigator and then show the File inspector you can make sure that these are checked:

[image]

Select your button on the storyboard. Then click the align button on the bottom right. Select "Horizontal Center in Container" and "Vertical Center in Container". Click "Add 2 Constraints".

[image]

If it wasn't perfectly centered already you may need to do one more thing. Click the "Resolve Auto Layout Issues" button that is two to the right of the align button. Choose "Update Frames" under "Selected Views".

[image]

Now when you run your app it should be centered no matter what device size you are using.

I learned all this from [Creating the user interface – Auto layout](http://codewithchris.com/6-creating-the-user-interface-auto-layout/). I recommend you check it out.