# Unable to adjust UILabel width programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, interface-builder, uilabel

I have been following several Q/A aboit this: like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26358146/ios-how-to-change-uilabel-width-based-on-text-length) and [this other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094753/how-to-adjust-and-make-the-width-of-a-uilabel-to-fit-the-text-size) one.

However **I am unable to change the width of a UILabel**.

Here is my code:

```
- (void)configureView {
    // Update the user interface for the detail item.
    if (self.detailItem) {
        Data *detailData = (Data*)self.detailItem;

        NSString * priceString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %.2f", detailData.priceCurrency, detailData.priceAmount.floatValue ];
        CGSize size = [priceString sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0f]}];
        CGSize adjustedSize = CGSizeMake(ceilf(size.width), ceilf(size.height));
        _price.frame = CGRectMake(_price.frame.origin.x, _price.frame.origin.y, 300, adjustedSize.height);

        // I Tried this one as well..
        //_price.frame = CGRectMake(_price.frame.origin.x, _price.frame.origin.y, adjustedSize.width, adjustedSize.height);
        _price.text = priceString;

        // and this one 
        // [_price sizeToFit];

        // And this one
        [_price setFrame:CGRectMake(_price.frame.origin.x,_price.frame.origin.y,adjustedSize.width,adjustedSize.height)];
        [_price setText:priceString];

        // as well as hardocding the width to 300
        // [_price setFrame:CGRectMake(_price.frame.origin.x,_price.frame.origin.y,300,adjustedSize.height)];
    }
}
```

Unfortunately none of the above changes the width UILabel.

This is how I set it up in Interface builder, is there something wrong here? **The original width is 40** so by hardcoding it to 300 I expected it to change.

[image]

The view is a **DetailView** which is accessed from a MasterViewController when the user taps on a cel. This is the code on DetailViewController that I use to call the configureView method described above.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [self configureView];
}
```

**Any idea on what I could be missing?**

This is how I initialize my outlets:

```
// DetailViewController.m 
@interface DetailViewController ()

@end

@implementation DetailViewController
@synthesize price = _price;
```

The good thing is that the text content is there so the outlet references **are not nil.**

However this is how the UILabel appears:

[image]

**EDIT:**

I tried to remove the constraints but it seems to be still not effective.

This is the code now:

```
   _price.frame = CGRectMake(_price.frame.origin.x, _price.frame.origin.y, 300, 200);
        _price.text = @"bdadadsdsdsdsDsds";
```

[image]

Comment: I believe the constraints are the problem.

Comment: I tried to change them but I am unsure on which one I should be changing.. any suggestion?

Comment: Did you set the width constraint? In the IB, see if you have a constraint with 40 in it.

Comment: BTW, comment out this line: `[_price setFrame:CGRectMake(_price.frame.origin.x,_price.frame.origin.y,adjustedSize.width,adjustedSize.height)];` and see if anything changes.

Comment: I did. See my EDIT picture. I also clicked on "clear all constraints". I tried to add a long string to the price label but would't do the job..

Comment: Setting the frame manually should not be done at all when your view has constraints on it. You must either set the width using just constraints, or set the position and size with just `frame`.

Answer (score 0):

The `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is the most appropriate place to modify the UI before it actually appears on the screen. Try to move your code to `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

Hope this helps